# How can I force a reinstall of a Windows update?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-update

I have a [Windows update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-043) that failed to uninstall correctly (I can see that cdd.dll is still the version contained in the bulletin and not the previous version).

I would like to force-install it so I can try uninstalling it again. Alternatively is there some way to re-uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already tried to uninstall the update, and that failed, I suggest using System Restore to a point prior to when the update in question was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to add/remove programs and uninstall windows updates from there. On earlier windows its listed straight in the program list while in Vista/7 there is a link on the side panel to view installed updates. After you have uninstalled it I am guessing it will try to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair your Windows with Windows CD and then try to reinstall or uninstall of that update.